# Java: Migrating from Apache Tiles 2 2.2.2 to Tiles 3 3.0.5

Tags: java, apache-tiles

I am in process of moving an old, legacy application to Tiles 3.
I could not find any info how or what are the equivalent in Tiles 3 for the following in Tiles 2:

```
org.apache.tiles.TilesApplicationContext
org.apache.tiles.context.ChainedTilesRequestContextFactory
org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextFactory
org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContext
org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory
org.apache.tiles.preparer.PreparerFactory
org.apache.tiles.reflect.ClassUtil
org.apache.tiles.renderer.AttributeRenderer
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.BasicRendererFactory
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

example:

```
public static HttpServletRequest getRequest(TilesRequestContext tilesContext) {
    HttpServletRequest request = null;

    if (tilesContext != null) {
      Object[] requestObjects = tilesContext.getRequestObjects();
......
}
....
return request;
}
```

where 'TilesRequestContext' is 
org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContext;
Which are no longer available in Tiles 3. 
What would be an equivalent replacement in Tiles 3 for the 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tiles/tiles-core/2.1.2/org/apache/tiles/context/TilesRequestContext.java

thank you,

Oleg

Comment: Have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

TilesRequestContext is available from TilesRequestContextHolder's getTilesRequestContext method.

```
import org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextHolder;
    @Override
        public void execute(Request request, AttributeContext attrCntxt) {
            TilesRequestContextHolder tilesReqCtxHldr = new TilesRequestContextHolder();
            tilesReqCtxHldr.setTilesRequestContext(request);
            tilesReqCtxHldr.getTilesRequestContext(); //TilesRequestContext
        }
```